# AS3 flash keyboard events spacebar issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

hi guys thank you so much for trying to help

Ok so the question is this. I am trying to move a movieclip automatically with

```
movieClip.x += xspeed ;
```

ofcourse this works but the point is i want this to be triggered with keyboard press ..problem is i couldn't a keyboard event which works as a mouse click..it works as long as space bar is pressed but if i release it ..it stops working..i want it to be like onclick it should start moving automatically.

Any ideas? thanks

hi thanks so much for your reply and sorry for the delay. Your code gave me an idea but I tried to write it without classes . It doesnt throw up any errors however it doesnt work either . I must be doing something stupid , please have a look and let me know . //rope coding

```
var ropey = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.fishyrope_mc.hitbox_mc.y ;
    trace(ropey);
    var ropemove:Boolean;


    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ropeCode);

    function ropeCode(e:Event):void
    {
                //detect keyboard spacebar click
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onSpacebarUp);

                function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
                {
                    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
                    {
                        ropemove = true;
                    } else if(ropey > 600 ) {
                        ropemove = false;
                    }

                }

                    //drop rope if variable = true

                    function dropRope(e:Event):void 
                    {

                        if(ropemove = true) {
                            MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.y += xSpeed;
                        } else if (ropemove = false) {
                            MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.y -= xSpeed;
                        }
                    }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyObj` extends `MovieClip` (or `Sprite`). Basically alls that's happening is you should just toggle a variable when you get the `KEY_UP` (not `KEY_DOWN`, as that will repeat if the key is held down). Then, every frame, check this variable, and if's it's good, move

Something like:

```
private var m_shouldMove:Boolean = false;

// constructor
public function MyObj()
{
    // add our listener for when we're added to the stage as we'll be adding events on it
    this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this._onAddedToStage );
}

private function _onAddedToStage( e:Event ):void
{
    // NOTE: the keyboard listener goes onto the stage
    // you'll also need to remove the events when your object is removed (e.g. REMOVED_FROM_STAGE)
    this.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this._onAddedToStage );
    this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );
    this.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, this._onKeyUp );
}

private function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    // every frame, if we should move, do so
    if( this.m_shouldMove )
        this.x += this.speed;
}

private function _onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE )
        this.m_shouldMove = !this.m_shouldMove; // toggle our var
}
```

**Update**

I've reworked your code sample, so it should work now:

```
var rope = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.fishyrope_mc.hitbox_mc;
var ropeMove:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ropeCode);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onSpacebarUp);

function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        ropeMove = !ropeMove; // toggles ropeMove (i.e. if it's true, sets it to false, and vice versa)
}

function ropeCode(e:Event):void
{
    // move the rope
    if( ropeMove )
    {
        rope.y += xSpeed;

        // stop moving if we've gone too far
        if( rope.y > 600.0 )
        {
            rope.y = 600.0;
            ropeMove = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I changed:

- Held your rope as a variable to make it easier to access
- Removed `ropey` as it's not needed (for your `> 600.0` check, you need to recalculate it anyway
- The keyboard event is now added with the enter frame event (you were adding a new keyboard event every frame
- The keyboard event listener just toggles the `ropeMove` var (there's no point checking for `> 600.0` here as it means you only check when any other key is pressed)
- The enter frame event simply moves the rope y
- In the enter frame event, if our y is too big, we stop moving

What the code is doing:

- We set up our vars - `rope` and `ropeMove` - `ropeMove` is used to know if we can move the rope or not
- We add our event listeners - one for the keybard event, to catch the spacebar key, and one enter frame event, so we can move our rope if necessary
- In the keyboard event, if our key is the spacebar, we toggle our `ropeMove` variable
- In the enter frame event, if `ropeMove` is true, we move our rope
- If our `rope.y` is greater than 600, we clamp it to 600, and set `ropeMove` to `false` so we stop moving

**Update 2**

With the addition of a variable `ropeDir`, the rope will now continuously move up and down (assuming `ropeMove` is `true`)

```
var rope = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.fishyrope_mc.hitbox_mc;
var ropeMove:Boolean = false;
var ropeDir:int = 1;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ropeCode);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onSpacebarUp);

function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        ropeMove = !ropeMove; // toggles ropeMove (i.e. if it's true, sets it to false, and vice versa)
}

function ropeCode(e:Event):void
{
    // move the rope
    if( ropeMove )
    {
        rope.y += xSpeed * ropeDir;

        // stop moving if we've gone too far
        if( rope.y > 600.0 && ropeDir == 1 )
            ropeDir = -1;
        else if( rope.y < 0.0 && ropeDir == -1 )
            ropeDir = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi please check my code above at the top , i tried to follow your idea without classes but its not working, thanks a lot for your help. If you could help me out a bit more would really appreciate it.

Comment: thank you so much man , and such a nice explanation for noobs like us. Just one problem, for some reason its not stopping at Y 600.

Comment: never mind i was making a mistake :) fixed it. thank you so much

Comment: Hi i have a question, what if when it reaches the desired depth , it should go back to its original spot. Any ideas on that? Thanks

Comment: Have a `dir` variable which can be either `1` or `-1`. Your rope y code becomes `rope.y += xSpeed * dir`, and your check `if( rope.y > 600 && dir == 1 ) { dir = -1 } else if ( rope.y < 0 && dir == -1 ) { dir = 1 }`

Comment: could I be bold enough and rude enough to request you to insert it into the code you wrote so that I can understand it a little better. Really sorry.

Comment: hey thanks a lot bro but I had figured it out myself few days back :)

Answer (score 0):

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveStarter);

function moveStarter():void
{
   addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startMove);
}
```

Comment: sorry that I wasnt clear enough addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, startMove); this is what I am using however the object only moves while the key is pressed down , i want the key to be pressed ones and then the object to continue moving without the key being pressed. Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: so, you mean you couldn't make what you want even with mouse click right? ok, i'm editing my answer then